# Problem in replacing a character in a number using TikZ and for loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, tex-core

I'm trying to write a for loop as a part of drawing a tikz picture using the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=12 pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{stix}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}

\newcommand \Label [1]{
    \tikzmath{ 
        \n = #1;
        if \n<0 
        then {\a= -1*\n;  {$\pgfmathprintnumber \a$$-$};}
        else { \a= \n; {$\a$};}
            ;}

}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x in {-13.1,-12.1,...,-1.1} {%
    \draw ($(\x,0) + (0,2pt)$) -- ($(\x,0) + (0,-2pt)$)
        node [below,below=0mm] {\Label \x};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I need to right the label `\x` in a custom format, so I defined the new command \Label.
I'm using `lualatex`
I need to make an extra feature in the `\Label` command which is to replace every "." in a number, if it exists, with the character "٫" and this is the point that I'm having a problem with.

I tried some commands using the `xstring` package but they did not work.
I have another restriction, that all the features should be in a single command which is `\label`.

Thank you!

Comment: Add `\tikzset{/pgf/number format/use comma}` in your preamble and all numbers printed by `\pgfmathprintnumber` use commas "," as decimal separators and periods "." as thousands separators (cf. p.952, pgfmanual v3.0.1a).

Comment: what is your actual problem ? Is Paul right about his guess?

Comment: Thank you, I used `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/dec sep={٫}}` and it works great :)

Answer (score 4):

The `\Label` macro appears to be be taking the absolute value. There is a [pgfmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfmath) function `abs()` for doing this so I would just replace `\Label`with a macro like:

```
\newcommand\abs[1]{\pgfmathparse{abs(#1)}\pgfmathresult}
```

Doing this produces:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=12 pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{stix}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}

\newcommand\abs[1]{\pgfmathparse{abs(#1)}\pgfmathresult}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {-13.1,-12.1,...,-1.1} {%
      \draw ($(\x,0) + (0,2pt)$) -- ($(\x,0) + (0,-2pt)$)
          node [below,below=0mm] {$\abs\x$};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```